# User not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported

Tags: linux, sudo, root

I need to install a package. For that I need root access. However the system says that I am not in sudoers file. When trying to edit one, it complains alike! How am I supposed to add myself to the sudoers file if I don't have the right to edit one?

I have installed this system and only administrator. What can I do?

**Edit**: I have tried `visudo` already. It requires me to be in sudoers in the first place.

```
amarzaya@linux-debian-gnu:/$ sudo /usr/sbin/visudo 

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for amarzaya: 
amarzaya is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
amarzaya@linux-debian-gnu:/$
```

Comment: Well, obviously `user not(is) the sudoers file`. (Typo in title)

Comment: You're on the naughty list now - http://xkcd.com/838/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It would be something of a security hole if you could add yourself to `/etc/sudoers` without having sudo or root access. Basically then anyone could make themselves root.

Basically you need to ask the administrators of that machine to add you, or to install the package for you, as per the policies of the site.

You should also be sure to use visudo to edit the sudoers file - it checks that the syntax is correct before writing the file. And you can use editors other than vi with visudo. It will by default use whatever you have set as `$EDITOR` and if you don't have it set you could do

```
# EDITOR=nano visudo
```

to use the nano editor instead.

Comment: I am the admin, since this is my machine and I have installed this system, but it doesn't help :(

Comment: If it is your system then you should have entered a password for the root user when installing. So login as 'root' and then do the visudo stuff.

Comment: Indeed. My fault. I have forgotten that I have entered the password during the installation back then.

Answer (score 25):

Login as root and use `/usr/sbin/visudo` to edit the file and add your username. Normal vi/vim will not be able to edit the file.

The easiest way is to just go down until you see the line "`root   ALL=(ALL)    ALL`" and add yourself under that with the same syntax (`yourusername ALL=(ALL) ALL`). Or, you can read the [sudoers manpage](http://www.courtesan.com/sudo/man/sudoers.html) if you want to give yourself more specific privileges.

Comment: It requires me to be in sudoers list in the first place in order to run visudo. I have installed this Debian, there no other admin.

Comment: If you are logged in as root, you don't need to run `sudo visudo`; just run `/usr/sbin/visudo`. But it looks like you already found this out, from the other answer's comments.

Comment: isn't enough to add the respective user to the "sudo" or "sudoers" (depending on the distro) group? Sadly in my case, it didn't work, but I could swear this used to work...?

Answer (score 9):

Just typed the command:

```
$ su
```

And asked for the password "root". Typed and boom... It worked!

This problem was my mistake. Due to be back at the facility at the time I created the username and password.

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful and saved my bacon! But i'm curious why simply adding this command and then the root password, would allow elevated privileges.... seems to rather defeat the purpose of the message "User not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported"

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest way, once you're root, is:

```
echo 'amarzaya ALL=(ALL) ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: You should be sure to use visudo to edit the sudoers file, rather than edit it directly or echo text to it.  This will ensure that it is syntactically correct, and ensure that you don't lock yourself out of access, or grant someone improper access.

Answer (score 1):

If your sudoers file already contains this kind of line

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Then, the cleanest way of doing things is probably to grant the `admin` group to your user.  For instance, to add *user* oracle to the `admin` *group*:

```
usermod -aG admin oracle
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. For me the cleanest as well, no messing with the sudoers file.

Comment: The correct command is `usermod -g oracle admin`

Comment: -1: the syntax is `usermod -g $group $user`. You're probably thinking of the `adduser` syntax, which is `adduser $user $group`.

Comment: …actually, you'll most likely want `usermod -aG $group $user`. `-g` sets the user's _primary_ group to the one you specify, and `-G` without `-a` will remove the user from groups that are not listed. `-g` will also change the group ownership of all files owned by the previous group in the user's home directory. So if you're like me and you have your umask set to `007`…

Comment: @BlacklightShining. You're right. The wrong syntax was proposed by a previous commenter and since `oracle` is often a group as well, there is indeed room for confusion.  I shouldn't have "corrected".

Answer (score -1):

In case you can still get root access using `su`, you can use this one-liner to add yourself to `/etc/sudoers/`:

```
su -c 'echo $USER ALL=(ALL)ALL >> /etc/sudoers'
```

To activate the change, log out and in again. For example end your the X Session or log out via shell enter `exit`.

Comment: -1: see [pkaeding's comment](https://superuser.com/q/120340#comment155005_120735).

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot use the `sudo` command, then you can use the following method:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Log the user out if the user is not root
3. Log in as root
4. Use root privileges
5. Log out (`exit`) – <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to get to the GUI

Comment: -1: This only works in _some_ local environments that actually have a GUI.

Answer (score -1):

All you need is add your `<username>` to `whell` group.

```
# usermod -aG whell username
```

Then login with your username and enjoy :)

Answer (score -3):

Sign in using the following first:

```
$ su
```

Then go ahead with:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

or whatever as normal

Comment: you don't need `su` - sudo does this.

Comment: They are not quite the same thing actually. sudo is 'do as super user', but you login with your user's password. su is 'switch user', and by default (without arguments) it attempts to switch to the root user, in which case you need to enter the root password. But you are also correct - using sudo after su is redundant, since you would already be the root user.

Comment: @aaron.newton I would actually read it as Switch User and DO; you can pick any user to run the command as with the `-u` flag. It _is_ mostly used for root, but so is `su`.

Comment: @aaron.newton I would actually read it as Switch User and DO; you can pick any user to run the command as with the `-u` flag. It _is_ mostly used for root, but so is `su`.